# How to merge multiple shapefile via ArcEngine 9.3 Java?

Tags: arcgis-engine, java

I try to merge the some shapefiles into one by using ArcEngine java platform.
  But it seem like that parameters of my merge class is wrong ,i google it a long time and     got nothing. Pls figure my problem out .The Error is :Invalid value type for parameter inputs.

```
public static  IGeoProcessorResult mergeTool(String shpPath,String[] shpNames,  String outFile) 
{  
    //Initialize the geoprocessorResult object
    //IGeoProcessorResult vGeoPR = null;
    // Initialize the geoprocessor.
    GeoProcessor vGeoP = null;
    IGeoProcessorResult vGeoPR = null;
    try {
        vGeoP = new GeoProcessor();
        IWorkspaceFactory vWSpaceFactory =new ShapefileWorkspaceFactory();
        //IFeatureClass vFeaCls = vFeatureWSpace.openFeatureClass(ShapeName);
       IWorkspace vWorkSpace; 
       IFeatureWorkspace vFeatureWSpace = null;
       vWorkSpace = vWSpaceFactory.openFromFile(shpPath, 0);
    vFeatureWSpace = (IFeatureWorkspace)vWorkSpace;
        IFeatureClass vFeaCls = null; 

        ArrayList<IFeatureClass> vInArray = new ArrayList<IFeatureClass>();
        for(int i=0;i<shpNames.length;i++)
        {

            vFeaCls= vFeatureWSpace.openFeatureClass(shpNames[i]);
            vInArray.add(vFeaCls);
        }
        //vGeoP.addMessage("I will overwrite your file if name exits!");
      // vGeoP.setEnvironmentValue("workSpace", vFeatureWSpace);
        vGeoP.setOverwriteOutput(true); 
         Merge  vMerge = new Merge(vInArray,outFile);
            vGeoPR=vGeoP.execute(vMerge,null);
            return vGeoPR;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out one way to solve this problem.We should set the input parameter format like this:

```
 String inputString = inputDir1+";"+inputDir2;
           Merge  vMerge = new Merge(inputString ,outFile);
```